# How can these graphs be plannar? Is there a good way to prove it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

I don't know how could I prove these graphs are plannar or not, the book does not give examples how to do so and i'm consufed.
Can someone show me how to do it? I'd appreciate

[image]

Comment: The link goes to an imgur which has ads on it and asks one to join.

Comment: @coffeemath i changed

Comment: Did whatever class you're taking / lectures you're taking notes on / text you're reading / etc. discuss necessary and sufficient conditions for graphs to be planar? Part (b) you should be able to do by inspection: just redraw it without crossings.

Comment: @runway44 I did, i'm just quite unsure about it. And, what about first graph? How could I prove so?

Comment: You did what? You found necessary and sufficient conditions? If so, put them in your question. Or you did draw the second graph? If so, submit your drawing.

Comment: @runway44 I did redraw the first one. I did find some conditions and so far it's plannar. I just do not know how to drawthe second or prove

Comment: Show how you redrew the first one. Also, isn't the second one *way* easier? Just move the vertices around until you get rid of the crossings.

Comment: I mean, I did draw the second, but not the first. I cant prove that its plannar

Comment: Hint: the first graph is not planar. Are you allowed to use Kuratowski's theorem? If so, you should try to apply it. If not, then you should at least know at least one result of the form "If G is planar, then [something]"; show that [something] is false.

Answer (score 1):

The graph 'a' is not planar since it contains the subgraph

$\{\{7,8\},\{1,8\},\{1,7\},\{2,7\},\{2,8\},\{4,7\},\{4,8\},\{1,2\},\{1,4\},\{2,4\}\}$

which is isomorphic to $K_5$, the complete graph with $5$ vertices.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph